# Join certain lines with sed

Tags: sed

I have an input which looks like this:

```
1
2

3
4
5

6
```

And I want to transform it with sed to :

```
12
345
6
```

I know it can be easily done with other tools but I want to do it specifically with sed as a learning exercise.
I have attempted this:

```
sed ':x ; /^ *$/{ N; s/\n// ; bx; }'
```

But it prints :

```
123456
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Maybe something like this: `s/\n([^\n])/\1/`?

Comment: wrt `I want to do it specifically with sed as a learning exercise` - an admirable goal but you'll be learning how to do something that you should never do so what's the point?

Comment: @EdMorton Well, the only way of learning sed is by actually **doing** stuff

Comment: Right but the only thing sed is best for is `s/old/new` on individual lines and you don''t need a whole lot of experience to learn how to do that. All the sed language constructs to do anything else (e.g. this) became obsolete literally about 40 years ago. So why not just learn the simple, robust, efficient, portable, maintainable ways to do everything with standard UNIX tools rather than learning how to write arcane sed scripts that might invoke the dark god Cthulu if you put a semicolon in the wrong place?

Comment: @EdMorton hahaha. I must admit I loled. It's just a matter of self improvement. Sed syntax is clunky and outdated ( as Perl ), but it's worth learning it even for historical reasons.

Comment: Yeah, I guess we're all interested in how the pyramids were built but it doesn't mean anyone's going to build a pyramid in their back yard any time soon. As long as you don't actually find yourself using it in your real software I suppose there's no harm in knowing some sed incantations...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Multiline-techniques):

> A common technique to process blocks of text such as paragraphs (instead of line-by-line) is using the following construct:
>
> ```
> sed '/./{H;$!d} ; x ; s/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/'
> ```
>
> 1. The first expression, `/./{H;$!d}` operates on all non-empty lines, and adds the current line (in the pattern space) to the hold space. On all lines except the last, the pattern space is deleted and the cycle is restarted.
> 2. The other expressions `x` and `s` are executed only on empty lines (i.e. paragraph separators). The `x` command fetches the accumulated lines from the hold space back to the pattern space. The `s///` command then operates on all the text in the paragraph (including the embedded newlines).

And indeed,

```
sed '/./{H;$!d} ; x ; s/\n//g'
```

does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW here's how to really do that task in UNIX:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v OFS= '{$1=$1}1' file
12
345
6
```

The above will work on any UNIX box.

Answer (score 1):

A GNU `awk` approach:

```
$ awk -F"\n" '{gsub("\n","");}1' RS='\n{2,}' file
12
345
6
```

Note it will add a trailing newline`\n` after last line.